# Need a regular expression to select Alphanumeric string with no special characters and atleast one number

Tags: javascript, c#

I need a regular expression to select Alphanumeric string with no special characters and at least one number in client side.

I tried (`?=.*[0-9]`) for at least one numeric character. For 'no special character', I do not want to specify each character in bracket.

Comment: What did you try - theres  veritable mass of regex examples and tutorials out there

Comment: Well, whilst you can use `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` for at least one alphanumeric character regex is not good on actually *counting* the number of occurences of a character. So you should use both a regex and some string-validation to achieve this.

Comment: what about special character, main problem I am facing with special character

Comment: If you could _edit_ your question to show us what you're trying, then maybe we can help.

Comment: example allowed string - 4rempe, Adkk3,js3EE
not allowed string - df@$#6a, Hkjk!^%^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
  ^(?=.*\d)[0-9a-zA-Z]+
```

Comment: your answer is right . I just add $ symbol and it worked ^(?=.*\d)[0-9a-zA-Z]+$